# How to change the origin in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[image: NAO]

I have problems when to try to load this robot:

[image: Problems_NAO]

[image: Problems_NAO]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5131/how-to-change-the-origin-in-gazebo?/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2013-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-12-18**:
How do you load the model? If from the world file, you can add there the spawning position, you can also add an offset in the robots .sdf file

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-12-18**:
I'm insert to Nao from Gazebo and I have problems when use .world file How can I add an offset in the robot .sdf file?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-12-18**:
Is your model given in URDF or SDF format?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-12-18**:
the model is SDF format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If your model is in SDF format, then you can add a `<pose>` element under the `<model>` tag which will apply an offset to the robot origin.

For example to raise the robot by 1 meter:

`<model name="nao">`

`<pose>0 0 1 0 0 0</pose>`

`<link ...`

`</model>`

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-12-18**:
a lot of thanks!!

**Comment by [Carbon Based Lifeform](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/725/carbon-based-lifeform/) on 2014-04-10**:
If I want to spawn a multi link robot with an offset on the z direction, do I have to specify the offset for each link or there's a more general command for this that moves the robot all at once?